# Search in undirectional list in C

Tags: c, list, search

I have a unidirectional list in C, I need to search for a phone number from it. However, I may not be able to search in an incomplete way, ie if I give a number in the format 111 222 33 * as a parameter, it can be any number. That is why I can see many numbers that meet this assumption. Does anyone have any idea what algorithm or how to do this?

for example:

> 123 456 789
>
> 111 222 333
>
> 123 231 123

and search:

> number = 123******

program must return first and third record.

Comment: I came across a little optimal idea. Create an array of size 10 ^ n, where n is the number of occurrences *. Then fill it with all possible combinations. But I just surrendered, because I know that with a lot of elements in the letter, the time will be significantly longer.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

What you **do not** want to do is to create an array with all possible combinations and then compare each one of them to each of the numbers in the list.

What you might want to do is:

```
// Assuming numbers in list are stored as strings, all of them are the
// same length and that the search string is also the same length.
// This also assumes that '*' in the search string is only matched to
// exactly one char ("123*" does not match "123456" but "123***" does). 

- Loop through all numbers in the list:
  {
    - Set variable 'match' to true.
    - Loop through all chars in search string:
      {
        - If that char is '*' then continue to next char in loop.
        - Else if that char is not the same as the char in same 
          position in that number (That is, n-th char in search
          string gets compared to n-th char in that number) then:
          {
            - Set variable 'match' to false.
            - End this loop (do not loop through more chars in search)
          }
      }
    - If variable 'match' is set to true then display that number (or
      add it to a result list or whatever you do want to do with those
      numbers that the search is supposed to find).
  }
```